# Is "unaided" an adjective or an adverb?

Tags: parts-of-speech

The Oxford Learner's Dictionary lists "unaided" as an adjective.
You can see it [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/unaided?q=unaided).

However, in two of the examples listed there:

- Did she produce this work unaided?
- He can now walk unaided.

Isn't "unaided" clearly acting as an adverb in these cases?

I'd appreciate some clarification. Thank you.

.

Comment: How can we know the dancer from the dance?

Comment: Most adjectives can be used as adverbs; indeed, most words of any kind can be used as any other kind in the right context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"unaided" is the adjective, modifying the *subject pronouns* in both the examples.

It doesn't modify the verbs, viz., "produce" and "walk". In other words, it doesn't add any description to the act of producing or walking.

Here's an example with an adverb: He walks slowly. "slowly" modifies how he walks (verb).

Let's try and see how it works, from a different perspective. Let's consider the affirmative sentence, "He can now walk unaided." Re-phrased, it would appear as follows:

"Unaided, he can now walk." - "unaided" doesn't describe how he walks. It qualifies "he" and his condition of being without help.

Answer (score 0):

Unaided can be used as an adjective or an adverb — in both examples you've given, unaided is being used as an adverb, as you've mentioned, modifying "produce" and "walk" respectively.

From [Cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/unaided):

> **Unaided**
>   *adjective, adverb*
>
> without any help from anyone else; independently:
>
> - Since his accident, he hasn't been able to walk unaided.
> - The two explorers attempted an unaided walk across the South Pole.

(Their second example show usage as an adjective, where unaided modifies the noun "walk".)